# Parsing javascript array to C# object list

Tags: c#, javascript, arrays

I am geting Javascript array as a result from webrequest which need to be converted/parsed to C# object for further handling. Any suggestion of .NET library or this need to be done by regex? Thank you?

```
<script>
{
item = new Array();

item [0] = new Array();
item [0][0]='value01';
item [0][1]='value02';

item [1] = new Array();
item [1][0]='value10';
item [1][1]='value11';

item [2] = new Array();
item [2][0]='value10';
item [2][1]='value11';
}
</script>
```

I know that the above code looks like JSON but, I have it as a part of a received html code. Therefore I think I need to parse it in traditional mannor.

Comment: A javascript array is very commonly written as something called 'json' look it up there are many parsers for .NET

Comment: You get it in a string? What does your string look like?

Comment: That's how the array is being created, but chances are that's not at all how you're receiving it. You're probably receiving it in JSON, in which case you'd need to implement a JSON parser for c# (which there are several).

Comment: Hi, I am not getting it as JSON, but from downloaded HTML. The javascript array is used to present the data in HTML table .

Answer (score 2):

You could try JSON.net (http://json.codeplex.com/). You could get the nuget package within Visual Studio.

Here is an example of how to use it, taken from the official site:

```
string json = @"{
  'channel': {
    'title': 'James Newton-King',
    'link': 'http://james.newtonking.com',
    'description': 'James Newton-King's blog.',
    'item': [
      {
        'title': 'Json.NET 1.3 + New license + Now on CodePlex',
        'description': 'Annoucing the release of Json.NET 1.3, the MIT license and the source on CodePlex',
        'link': 'http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx',
        'category': [
          'Json.NET',
          'CodePlex'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}";

// LINQ to JSON
// ------------
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
string itemTitle2 = (string)jObject["channel"]["item"][0]["title"];
```

Comment: Thank you .... but pls read above. the script is within downloaded HTML